# Array vacio con Inner Join

Tags: mysql

Tengo unas tablas relacionadas, al hacer un `SELECT` me trae toda la info normal y con `INNER JOIN`, pero hay una tabla de boletas que tengo, estoy haciendo `INNER JOIN`, ahora cuando voy a detalle de un vehiculo, la info que normalmente me trae solamente se muestra cuando tengo registrado una boleta, y los vehiculos que no tiene boleta no me trae nada, hice un `var_dump` y viene vacio a menos que ese vehiculo tuviera registrado al menos una boleta si me trae toda la información.

```
SELECT * FROM vehiculos
   INNER JOIN boletas ON vehiculos.control = boletas.control
WHERE vehiculos.control = :control
```

si quito el `INNER JOIN` entonces si me trae nuevamente toda la info, pero claro ya me tira error donde estaba mostrando la información de las boletas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En vez de usar `INNER JOIN` utiliza `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT * FROM vehiculos
LEFT JOIN boletas ON vehiculos.control = boletas.control
WHERE vehiculos.control = :control
```

Comment: Ok, funciona me muestra la información pero ahora pasa algo, estaba mostrando el numero de control, $datos["control"], ahora los que no tienen boleta no los muestra, esa información esta en vehículos. Ese dato si debe existir independiente de que se tenga boleta o no.

Answer (score 0):

Podrías usar `RIGHT JOIN`  y probar también con la respuesta anterior, lo importante es que cuando hay información en una tabla y en la otra no la condición del `INNER JOIN` no se cumple por lo cual debes usar el `RIGHT O LEFT` mostrando los resultados de la tabla madre incluso si no posee registros de relación.   [Ejemplo con Grafico](http://www.aulaclic.es/sql/graficos/resumen_multitabla.gif)

```
      SELECT vehiculos.control as boletavehiculo, boletas.control as 
      boletacontrol FROM vehiculos 
      LEFT JOIN boletas ON boletavehiculo = boletacontrol 
      WHERE boletavehiculo = :control
```

Comment: Ya lo probé en ese caso no me devuelve ningún dato array(0) { }, con LEFT JOIN si me muestra los datos del vehiculo aunque no tengan boleta pero el valor de control viene null, el resto si salen.

Comment: intenta por descarte eliminar el WHERE y fijate que  el valor que estas comparando en el WHERE no tiene NULL

Comment: Quite where para ver xd, pero el resultado es lo que esperaba mas no lo que necesito, ya que me trae todo, tengo que el where para solo mostrar la info del vehiculo con el ID que se selecciono anteriormente, ahora los vehiculos que tienen boleta si muestra los numero de control, esos funcionan normal, el incoveniente esta en los que no tienen boleta, con LEFT JOIN se soluciono de que no saliera la info pero ahora solo no muestra el numero de control, que esta en vehiculos y segun eso lo traigo todo. Creo el INNER me esta creando algun conflicto. porque sin eso todo funciona bien.

Comment: tendras que colocarle prefijo a la consulta, el campo ID de vehiculo tiene el mismo nombre que el de boletas? si es así aveces crea conflicto y toma el ultimo valor en este caso el de boletas que es null

Comment: Ahora si, era eso xd, le agregue un prefijo a la de boleta, ahora si muestra el numero de control aunque no tenga ningun registro de boleta. Muchas gracias.

Comment: a su orden, yo pase 2 semanas con este problema y al final son los benditos prefijos ,asi que ya no uso el (*) y le coloco prefijo a todo.

Answer (score -1):

inner join te trae solo los datos que comparten las tablas unidas por PK Y FK, si algun dato no existe en una tabla, no lo traerá en la otra. Ahi tienes que entrar a revisar si tu MER esta bien hecho y si tus relaciones estan bien hechas

Comment: perfecto que bien que lo hayas resuelto saludos :D

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]